# Getting next element

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

I need to get a next (sibling) element of the one with "Yes" as its text. I can use the text "Yes", css and part of the id, but the number (e.g.. 106) is unfortunately excluded. Also I can't directly get that sibling, because of that exclusion. Here is a part of the HTML code:

```
<a style="right: auto;" class="x-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item" id="button-106">
  <span id="button-106-btnWrap" role="presentation" class="x-btn-wrap" unselectable="on">
    <span id="button-106-btnEl" class="x-btn-button" role="presentation">
      <span id="button-106-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center">Yes
      </span>
      <span role="presentation" id="button-106-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon-el">
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

I came up with this query, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
By.XPath(".//*[text() = 'Yes' and contains(id(), '-btnInnerEl')/following-sibling::*]")
```

How can I alter this query so I can get the next element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the span with id `button-106-btnIconEl`:

```
//span[contains(@id,'-btnInnerEl')][normalize-space(text())='Yes']/following-sibling::span
```

Comment: The key here is that the content is 'Yes' followed by a bunch of white space.  "FirePath" is your friend tracking down these sorts of things!